# sys.path run in Jupyter file in Visual Studio Code evaluates to a "filter object" instead of list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, pipenv, modulenotfounderror

- When I run the following inside a Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code with kernel pointing to the local virtual environment (created with pipenv),

running below code inside Jupyter returns a filter object (not a list of path strings!)

```py
import sys
sys.path
```

<filter at 0x10f47efb0>

2. if I open a shell with the same virtual environment, it returns the EXPECTED list...

```py
❯ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/Users/vincentricci/Documents/Development/PYTHON', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/pygments/2.15.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
```

3. If I pick a different KERNEL and stick to the original Anaconda installation, then the same Jupyter file executes fine and shows me the expected path

['/Users/vincentricci/Documents/Education/AI_and_Machine_Learning/AI_ML_week6_data_clustering_and_principal_component_analysis',
'/Users/vincentricci/Documents/Development/PYTHON',
'/Users/vincentricci/opt/anaconda3/lib/python39.zip',
'/Users/vincentricci/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9',
'/Users/vincentricci/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
'',
'/Users/vincentricci/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
'/Users/vincentricci/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aeosa',
'/Users/vincentricci/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
'/Users/vincentricci/.ipython']

Main reason I wish to solve this is that with my current virtual environment + Jupyter setup, when I try "import numpy as np" and use Kernel set to the virtual environment installation below..

```py
❯ python3 -m site
sys.path = [
    '/Users/vincentricci/Documents/Education/AI_and_Machine_Learning/AI_ML_week6_data_clustering_and_principal_component_analysis',
    '/Users/vincentricci/Documents/Development/PYTHON',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/pygments/2.15.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/vincentricci/Library/Python/3.11' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/vincentricci/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

The following code in Jupyter notebook with Kernel using above Virtual environment gives me this error  (IF instead I run the same inside the virtual environment shell, it works fine)

import numpy as np

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

There must be a mistmatch between the PATH used by Jupyter inside VS Studio code and the path provided by the virtual environment.... Not sure what the issue is...

Appreciate any pointed help.

Comment: Could you by any chance add the `pipenv` version to the question?  It looks like some code is using the `filter` function` and expecting it to return a list (like in Python 2.x) and assigning that to `sys.path`.